# Make Restangular .remove() work with Rails Shallow Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, restangular

Say, I have nested resources as follows,

```
shallow do
  resources :aalu do
    resources :pyaj
  end
end
```

Using restangular I get the resources as required using the following `Restangular` call

```
all_pyaj = Restangular.one('aalu', $stateParams.aaluId).all('pyaj').getList();
```

`pyaj` is an element of the `all_pyaj` array, I get it using ng-repeat.

Now, When I want to remove the resource using Restangular using `remove()` method, 
the `pyaj.remove()` makes a DELETE call to `/aalu/:aalu_id/pyaj/:pyaj_id`

I want it to make a DELETE call to `/pyaj/:pyaj_id` and remove the resrouce form the angular $scope too.

I can achieve this by the following way,

```
Restangular.one('pyaj', payj.id).remove().then(
   function (response) { /* Problem: Delete this pyaj from $scope */ }
```

Can I make Restangular make a DELETE call to `/pyaj/:pyaj_id` and remove the resource form the angular $scope too?

How Restangular works with shallow routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure Restangular with `RestangularProvider.setParentless(['pyaj']);` to tell it that any `pyaj` object should be "shallow". See https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setparentless.